# Relationship History

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, relationship, status

I'm pretty new to Facebook development and am trying to wrap my head around the what you do and don't have access to.  I've done some searching through the forums and the googles but haven't found much on getting historical data.

I would like to access two things from an 'authenticated' user:
 1) Is a history of relationship status' of their immediate friends.  - It doesn't look like Facebook gives out past information, but thought I would put it out there.

2) Once you have user authenticated are you able to access their friends likes/dislikes, interests?

Thanks for all the help in advance its much appreciated!

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook friend history is not available. Only current list of friends is, and there is no date available as to when they became freinds.  You can get a lot of information about friends by asking for [extended permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) such as `friends_likes`, `friends_interests`, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info OffBySome.  Would be nice if it were available though.